# The model item passed into the dictionary is of type... But I have good type in view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

Hello I have a problem when running my app I have an error like this:

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[SR.Models.Incydent]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'SR.Models.Incydent'.

I know that it's caused because in view may be bad reference to model.
But my action looks like:\

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult ZglosIncydent()
    {
        return View();
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult ZglosIncydent(Incydent incydent)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            incydent.Id = incydent.generateID();
            incydent.DateAdded = DateTime.Now;
            incydent.Status = "NO";
            incydent.Localization = "{52.1234, 53.1234}";
            incydent.Phone = "+48159623478";

            dbIncydent.Incydents.Add(incydent);
            dbIncydent.SaveChanges();

            setFlash("Zgłoszenie Przyjęte", MyController.SUCCESS);

            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Index", new { Area = "SR" });
        }
        return View(incydent);
     }
```

And in my View:

```
@model SR.Models.Incydent

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Zgłoś Incydent";
    Layout = "~/Areas/SR/Views/Shared/_SRLayout.cshtml";
}

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken();
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true);
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="input-group" style="width: 50%;">
            <label for="Type">Typ Incydentu</label>
            <select class="form-control" id="Type" name="Type" required="required" style="width: 100%">
                <option value="WS">Wypadek Samochodowy</option>
                <option value="P">Pożar</option>
                <option value="Z">Zasłabnięcie</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="input-group" style="width: 50%;">
            <label for="Description">Opis</label>
            <textarea id="Description" class="form-control" name="Description" required="required" style="resize: none;" rows="5"></textarea>
        </div>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="Zgłoś Incydent" class="btn btn-default" />
}
```

When I saw the error I thought that line with @model cause the problem but it has a proper type. In controller I have second action View which return IENumerable and it's work fine.

Below View and Index action.

```
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Index", new { Area = "SR" });
        }
        [HttpGet]
        [Authorize(Roles = "Koordynator")]
        public ActionResult View(String Type = "", String Status = "", String Order = "")
        {
            var Incydents = from s in dbIncydent.Incydents select s;
            switch (Order)
            {
                case "id_desc":
                    Incydents = Incydents.OrderByDescending(s => s.Id);
                    break;
                case "id_asc":
                    Incydents = Incydents.OrderBy(s => s.Id);
                    break;
                case "date_desc":
                    Incydents = Incydents.OrderByDescending(s => s.DateAdded);
                    break;
                case "date_asc":
                    Incydents = Incydents.OrderBy(s => s.DateAdded);
                    break;
                case "type_desc":
                    Incydents = Incydents.OrderByDescending(s => s.Type);
                    break;
                case "type_asc":
                    Incydents = Incydents.OrderBy(s => s.Type);
                    break;
                case "status_desc":
                    Incydents = Incydents.OrderByDescending(s => s.Status);
                    break;
                case "status_asc":
                    Incydents = Incydents.OrderBy(s => s.Status);
                    break;
                default:
                    Incydents = Incydents.OrderBy(s => s.DateAdded);
                    break;
            }

            if (Type != "all" && Status != "all")
                Incydents = Incydents.Where(s => s.Status.Contains(Status) && s.Type.Contains(Type));
            else if (Type != "all" && Status == "all")
                Incydents = Incydents.Where(s => s.Type.Contains(Type));
            else if (Type == "all" && Status != "all")
                Incydents = Incydents.Where(s => s.Status.Contains(Status));
            return View(Incydents.ToList());
        }
```

Comment: Show your `Index` method.

Comment: 1) Make sure the right view is being called. The error screen should indicate which view Razor tried to process 2) Check things like your layout and any partial views your view may be using. It's possible one of these has a model that's not being satisified.

Comment: Clearly somewhere your are passing `IEnumerable<Incydent>` to that view. Most obvious from the code you have posted is that the view returned by `Index()` is `IEnumerable<Incydent>`. Is that `Index.cshtml` calling the `Incydent.cshtl` as a partial?

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
```

to

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("ActionNameHere", "ControllerNameHere", FormMethod.Post)
```

So that the `form` knows where to `POST` it's data.

Comment: That's only necessary when you posting back to a controller or method that not the same name as the GET method that rendered the view. And this does not answer the question.